# Is there any way we can arrive at a general principle of magnetic character based on the bond order (ie; fractional or integral)?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

So, after going through two assignments on Chemical Bonding and the Molecular Orbital theory, I saw that in most of the problems where we were asked about the magnetic character of a molecule (paramagnetic or diamagnetic), I noticed that almost all of the paramagnetic molecules had fractional bond orders, whereas almost all diamagnetic ones had a whole number bond order. I highly doubt if it is a general rule, though. If so, what is the reasoning for this, and is there any other general pattern that relates bond order to magnetic character ? Sorry if the questions seems trivial.

Comment: A simple explanation for the paramagnetism of odd-electron species is you need two to make a pair.

Comment: An Oxygen molecule has two unpaired electrons and is paramagnetic and bond order 2.